# rounding to two decimals for classification

Tags: javascript

I have a set of classes ranges used for classification of dataset.

```
dataset: [ 0.44531, 0.79456, 1.47574, 4.53429]

//the classes ranges
min1 = 0.44531 
max1 = 1.23355
min2 = 1.23355 
max2 = 4.53429
```

If I use math.round() or .toFixed() to round the ranges some data will be thrown outside of the ranges of min1 and max2

Is there a way to round to two decimals and be sure that no data could be outside?

Comment: Use `Math.floor` on the minimum variables, and `Math.ceil` on the maximum variables instead of `Math.round`

Comment: if I do that max1 will be higher than min2

Comment: ok I think I will have to round the data first... probably that's the only solution

Comment: If the range increments in steps, just set the next min to the same as the previous max, and then set the max for the current with Math.ceil etc.

Comment: So you have min_1..n, max_1..n, and data, where every item in data is inside [min_x, max_x] for some x, and you want to round every min and max in such a way that max_x is still less than min_(x + 1) for every x, but the dataset isn’t rounded and the items still fall into the same ranges? That’s not possible in general…

Comment: Please clarify the expected value of ```min1```, ```max1```, ```min2```, ```max2``` and an example of a value that could _become outside the range_

Comment: @minitech : yes you are right, I figured it out just now. The only way is to round the data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value = Math.floor(value * 100) / 100;
```

That should do the trick, works also with `Math.round` and `Math.ceil`. (I don't guaranty that works for all 100% numbers, sometimes decimal values are strangely stored in computer memory, I don't know how javascript does in these cases.)

Comment: that makes min1 = 0.45 and some data is thrown outside the range. With Math.floor and Math.ceil, max1 become higher than min2, and some data could be in two classes in same time

Comment: @below-the-radar Have you tried using ```Math.floor``` for both min and max values ?

Comment: some data would be outside max2 if using Math.floor everywhere... I think rounding the data is the only option for classification. by the way sorry for the -1, I gave you +1